# How to keep secure the fabric api key in android?

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

I am using this example but still i need to write my [fabric](/questions/tagged/fabric) API key in `AndroidManifest.xml`..

https://github.com/plastiv/CrashlyticsDemo/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read this before you post your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this steps:-

https://github.com/plastiv/CrashlyticsDemo/

mostly people have to problem run the gradle command line so you can use like this:

1) Open terminal.

2) Go to your project work space

3) ./gradlew

(Note if permission denies error use this command- chmod 744 gradlew and again run ./gradlew)

(4) ./gradlew assemble -P apiKey=Your fabric api key

Now you can fully secret your api key but remember one thing your fabric.properties looks like that

fabric.properties:-

apiSecret=”Your fabric secret key” apiKey=”Your fabric api key”

Enjoy!
You dont need to write your fabric key in your AndroidManifest.xml....

Comment: Ok that's wprking fine...
Thanks!

Comment: I am getting this error after removing key from manifeest Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'. > Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

Comment: As a heads up, you may need to disable Instant Run on Android Studio for this solution to work.